# Can a Drawable be used as a Shader somehow?

Tags: android

I'm aiming to update an SVG library I've written to support the use of pattern fills. In one particular SVG file I'm looking at that makes use of a pattern fill, the pattern is itself defined in terms of shapes (as opposed to an external or embedded bitmap).

To be able to handle this, what I considered doing is to have the parser create a `Drawable` that draws the shapes defined by the pattern, and then to somehow use that `Drawable` as a `Shader` for the `Paint`.

Unfortunately it seems that no such thing as a `DrawableShader` exists, and to implement something like this myself would mean delving into native code from what I can see from the source of existing `Shader` classes.

I think the only solution for me is to render the pattern tile to a `Bitmap` and then use `BitmapShader`. This is okay, though to avoid potential quality issues of scaling `Bitmap`s I prefer to keep absolutely everything as a set of vectors.

Before I go down the `Bitmap` and `BitmapShader` route, is there another way I have overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer is "no". For this reason, I used `BitmapShader` in the end.